# Angular 8, User input and updated along with user input and selected check mark

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, user-interface, angular8

In Angular 8, after user input "$10" and `click(Onclick event)`, the box underneath should be updated with what user input and the entire box should be selected as shown in the picture.

Any tutorials, advice would be appreciated

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zEYs.png)

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-0.8">
              <label class="padding_7">Costs</label>
</div>

<!-- Get user input (Only positive number) and need to be updated -->
<div class="col-md-1">
              <input type="positive-number" />
</div>

<div class="col-md-2">
            <button data-target="something" data-toggle="sth model" type="round-button custom-button">Update Cost</button>
</div>
```

Any Idea in Component.ts ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you are looking for a prototype, can you check the fiddle.
I have created a prototype for the question, please check it

[Check fiddle](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nt68ab)

Comment: Thanks!! Big Help!! Appreciated it!

Comment: Welcome bro, could you mark it as correct answer if it helped

Answer (score 1):

Try Property Binding, Pass the value in Ts or catch it via form ,Then dynamic  the property  [checked]  in ts.

Comment: Sure thing. let me try! Thanks!!